# Aligning text to a path in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, expression-blend

I'm working on a small part of an application that requires us to draw shapes for the user to see. I'm using a path to display the shape, specifically binding a PathSegmentCollection to the  PathGeometry.Figures like this --

```
<Path Name="Shape"
  Stretch="Uniform"">
<Path.Data>
    <PathGeometry>
        <PathGeometry.Figures>
            <PathFigureCollection>
                <PathFigure IsClosed="True"
                            Segments="{Binding Segments}"
                            StartPoint="{Binding StartPoint}" />
            </PathFigureCollection>
        </PathGeometry.Figures>
    </PathGeometry>
</Path.Data>
```

Somewhere on that shape, a logo will be shown, but due to the variance in the shapes, I'm struggling to think of a solution where the logo text will always be shown on the shape (the shapes can be anything, even from a DXF file).

Here's an illustration of the problem --

[image: Logo issue image]

The left image is what I have, but the right image is what I want.

Right now I'm drawing the logo as just a textblock on a grid that's bound to the size of the shape. I ended up going this route to keep the text automatically scaled to the correct height no matter the scaled units of the shape.

Ideally what I'd like to do is place a textblock inside a path, but I know that's not possible. I was wondering if anyone had any good ideas on how to align this text to the shape no matter what shapes come up.

In theory I'd like to be able to align it to all the regular orientations (top-left, top-center, bottom-right etc).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Frankly, your biggest problem at this point appears to be the lack of a complete specification. While I understand the aesthetic appeal of the positioning you've shown above in your example, there's no obvious reason that position should even be considered "bottom-left"). It's clearly not the left-most location, so you've apparently arbitrarily decided the vertical alignment takes precedence over horizontal alignment. Given horizontal alignment precedence would result in the text located at the corner touching the left of the bounding rectangle. Other algorithms could produce different results

Comment: In addition, while the figure you show is a regular, convex shape, you say these figures could be anything. A good specification will work for any input. Maybe for the moment, you'd be better off breaking your question down into more manageable (and clear) parts. For example, _part_ of the problem seems to be identifying the outer boundary of the path. You might consider asking that question first. As a bonus, it would be easier for you to provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go with the question in that case.

Comment: this is not simple at all. The output here should be a point (or at least some offset) where you can place the `TextBlock` (or draw text). The valid condition here is that point should be contained in the PathGeometry, and maybe just lie on the stroke. When it comes to dynamic shape, the meaning of `left-top`, `bottom-right`, ... is not consistent, I would prefer to concept of lowest-possible, left-most possible... or some ***angle*** between the line (connecting center to the point we need to find) and the horizontal line. Combining all those, u may need some scanning to find that point.

Comment: Peter, I'm not looking for the full blown solution. Just some ideas. I thought my question explains the problem pretty clearly.    King, its a good idea, I'll have to look into that idea. I still like top-left even though I know it.will be tough to define.